# Is $$isocateScope:true the right way to make all the link functions of all directives on a node use the isolate scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a node with an isolate scope directive. There are more directives on the node, which have link functions. These link functions do not have the isolated scope as first argument, but the root scope for example. Unless I use `$$isolateScope:true` in these directives. It works: all the link functions have the isolated scope as first argument. But `$$isolateScope` is a private property. Is there also another way? There is also a function `markDirectivesAsIsolate`. But how could I use it?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: I am not aware of the $$isolateScope property, but I am aware that the double dollar sign attributes(starting with $$) are used internally by Angular and are subject to change so it's not recommended to depend on them.

Comment: If other directives use the same scope then it isn't exactly isolated.

Comment: @zeroflagL, I thought isolate scope concerns a node. I have multiple directives on the same node.

Comment: An isolate scope is only relevant for directives using a template in order to isolate (sic!) the template from the rest of the application. Maybe you could explain your situation.

Comment: @zeroflagL, I have made the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ericjvandervelden/E3LTK/3/). It doesn't work. but on my machine it does. I want the link functions of the  `fl` and `sp`  directives to get the isolate scope of the foo directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment an isolate scope is only relevant for directives using a template in order to isolate (sic!) the template from the rest of the application.

Based on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericjvandervelden/E3LTK/3/) you provided the directives can also communicate through foo's controller:

```
controller:["$scope",function($scope){
  $scope.ab = []
  this.addFl = function() {
    $scope.ab.push("fl") 
  }

...

app.directive("fl",function(){
  return{
    require:"foo",
    link:function(scope,element,attrs, fooController){
      fooController.addFl();
```

Comment: I know. But i thought: should addFl be a function of the controller, or of the isolate scope. Look at the bottom of the [following page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngController) where it can be done in two ways, and I wanted to try the second one.

Comment: It's not accurate but as a rule of thumb: You put into a scope only what is referenced in the HTML source: `<span>{{name}}</span>` => `name` must be in the scope. `ng-click="greet()"` => `greet()` must be in the scope. No reference to `addFl()` => doesn't need to be in the scope. You can have it both in the scope and as a method of the controller, if it's necessary. The two options are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much, an eye opener for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the directives' scopes isolated using an empty object as scope description:

```
scope: {},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // ...
}
```